# WolfSSL on FreeRTOS communication with Linux

Tags: linux, freertos, wolfssl

I'm trying to establish a secure communication between the FreeRTOS (client) and Linux (server) using the WolfSSL library.

I'm getting the error -501 that indicates that cipher suites list doesn't match.

Here the cipher suites that the clients send on FreeRTOS:

[image: ggggggggggggg]

Here the cipher suites that the server support on Linux:

[image]

How can I enable the one of those cipher suite on Linux to enable the communication?

Best regards,

Comment: Hi user3068649,
Does having a specific suite set on the linux server have the same issue. For example starting the server with
./examples/server/server -l DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256 -b
Setting the example server to have only the preferred suite the client wants available. (TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES256_SHA256) This suite should be enabled with the default wolfSSL configuration
./configure
make

Answer (score 0):

@user3068649

Like sweetness mentioned you can try specifying a list of ciphers with the -l option when starting the server this list can contain many ciphers with a colon (:) separator.

For other questions please visit our forums: http://www.wolfssl.com/forums/
Or contacts us: info@wolfssl.com